# Is Zhang always psychic?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Slingshot's [Shaojie Zhang](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Shaojie_Zhang) turned out to be psychic on my first playthrough. Is that always the case or was I just lucky?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you just got lucky.

Comment: @Shadur Fairly sure as in you experienced him being not psychic? I'd accept a screenshot showing the respective test result as answer. Unfortunately proving you wrong would be much more tedious since that would require _many_ playthroughs (at different difficulty levels) none of which must leave Zhang ungifted...

Comment: Fairly sure as in it's been a while since I last played through and I don't recall him testing as psychic. If I had anything more solid I'd have given an actual answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Shadur I see, thanks for the input nonetheless, that lowers my optimism on obtaining at least one definitely gifted soldier justifying the early appearance of some nasty xenomorphs...

Comment: @Shadur Do you still have such a savegame? It'd suffice showing a screenshot of the Psi-Lab's soldier selection screen with a greyed out Zhang to prove this

Comment: Maybe. Also don't have access to my game computer right now as I'm at work.

Comment: its probably just chance since he comes at high rank which means his will is high, making him more likely to be psychic

Comment: didnt get psi at my games

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have played through the game about 6 times now (10 past the Psychic Ablity point) and never had a Zhang that was Psychic... I am working on an 11th time, and will take a screenshot when I get him to that point again.  So I think you got Lucky!!  Gratz!! :D

[image: Zhang as a non-psychic]